# Is there a way to not display the skill icon on the amazon Echo Show?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo-show

I made full-screen images for the Amazon Echo Show and would like to display them without the skill's icon in the top right corner. Is this possible? I would prefer to brand my content in a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It actually looks like doing this is not currently supported :(](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/93412/remove-app-icon-from-card.html)